# how can I modify the source code of jhipster and change the display of entity to jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jhipster

I am a beginner and I do not know much about JHipster . My problem is that I need to change at the source code generator JHipster to change the display of the entities created by this generator , I need to display all entities generated in a jhipster jqGrid .
What I realized is that I have to change at the generators \ Entity \ templates \ src \ main file \ webapp \ app \ entities \ _entity - management.html but I 'm stuck and I do not know what I have to change exactly .
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 possibilities:

1. change the generated code, it's yours
2. [fork the generator](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-generator-development-setup) and adapt it to your needs
3. create a [jhipster module](http://jhipster.github.io/modules/creating-a-module/)

Which one you choose is up to you but for #2 and #3 you will have to go for #1 anyway to understand the technology. In any case, take time to learn both spring-boot and angularjs.

I would not recommend using jqGrid for an Angular app, you'd better use a grid that has built-in support for angular like [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) or [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have already chosen the first option and I am trying to change the generated code, but the code seems complicated.
Could you tell me why you I would not recommend using jqGrid for an Angular app,
I really don’t have a big idea about Angularjs, Could you tell me please what is the difference between ag-grid, ui-grid and jqGridn.

Comment: Well it's just that JQuery (and plugins)  uses a very different programming model than AngularJS, so when switching to AngularJS it's better to embrace it.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your help, but after changing the code how can I test the modified jhipster generator and how can I know that my new jhipster is doing well ?